# Update numpy 2d array indexing from another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a numpy way to do the below without using a loop?

```
A = np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5]])
I = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1])
V = np.array([6, 6, 6, 6, 6])
```

I want to update A such that it has 6 in the corresponding index specified by I. So A becomes ...

`A = np.array([[6,1],[2,6],[6,3],[4,6],[5,6]])`

Tried the following, but they did not work..

```
A[I] = V
A[:,I] = V
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `A[np.arange(len(A)), I] = V`:

```
In [15]: import numpy as np                                                                                              

In [16]: A = np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5]])                                                                   

In [17]: I = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1])                                                                                   

In [18]: V = np.array([6, 6, 6, 6, 6])                                                                                   

In [19]: A[np.arange(len(A)), I] = V                                                                                     

In [20]: A                                                                                                               
Out[20]: 
array([[6, 1],
       [2, 6],
       [6, 3],
       [4, 6],
       [5, 6]])
```